# Backpressure with Spring Webflux and several slow HTTP-backend requests

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

In my webflux-application I am consuming messages from AWS-SQS and use them to invoke several HTTP-requests on a slow backend (response times up to 5 seconds).

I realized that the more messages I consume, the slower the backend gets, until it dies, due to too much traffic.

How can I use the reactor / webflux mechanism, to control the number of requests I send to a backend? I tried some stuff with limit / limitRate, but it didn't work as expected.

Do you have any samples/ideas?

Comment: [`Flux.limitRate()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#limitRate-int-int-) could well be helpful here, but you'll have to be careful to ensure your source Flux reading from SQS deals with those backpressure signals appropriately.

Comment: it might be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244808/backpressure-mechanism-in-spring-web-flux/52245213#52245213

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [resilience4j](https://resilience4j.readme.io/) library. Among several resiliency features like circuit breaker, retry, bulkhead there is [rate limiting](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/ratelimiter) as well.

They support [Project Reactor](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/examples-1#section-decorate-mono-or-flux-with-a-ratelimiter).